# How to access the Android MediaStore in NativeScript?

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

I would like to open the Android Recorder and am using the following code:

```
let intent: Intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
```

Unfortunately, NativeScript doesn't know "MediaStore". How can I import this definition?

Comment: Access the classes by their full package name. Obviously MediaStore in and of itself is a vague definition of what you want to do in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the full package name to access the MediaStore, so as documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html), you need to reference: `android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION`

The same is true for Intent, documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and looks like this:
`new android.content.Intent();`

If you are using TypeScript, I would highly recommend you install the platform type definitions, which you can get [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-platform-declarations). In a good editor, it will be able to show you what you can do when you are typing.

[image]